# Are two limits of probabilities of "random variable is equal to zero" and "random variable bigger than any eps>0" are complementations of each other?

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, probability-theory, limits, probability-limit-theorems

I'm studying some theorems in theory of probability and in some of them is used such an expression.

$$Let\space\{\xi_n, n \in \mathbb{N}\}$$
is a sequence of non-negative random variables, than if:
$$\forall \epsilon > 0\lim_{n \to \infty} P(\xi_n >\epsilon) = 0  $$
than something...

Is it correct to replace this expression with this:
$$Let\space\{\xi_n, n \in \mathbb{N}\}$$
is a sequence of non-negative random variables, than if:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} P(\xi_n = 0) =1  $$
than something...

My thoughts:
It is correct because probability of being equal to zero and probability of being greater than any positive eps > 0 intuitively are complementations of each other. But intuition is a bad science.

Comment: I would have thought $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} P(\xi_n = 0) =1$ implies $\forall \epsilon > 0:\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} P(|\xi_n| >\epsilon) = 0$ but not the other way round

Comment: it's trivially false; consider e.g. $\xi_n=1/n$ (degenerate random variables even),

Comment: @vanderWolf thanks, your example is really clear

Comment: @vanderWolf You should post that example as an answer so the question can be marked as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's trivially false; consider e.g. $\xi_n=1/n$
(degenerate random variables).